# R manipulate strings to make a certain length

Tags: r

I have a list of numbers (used as characters), for instance,

```
IDs <- as.character(c('0', '01', '002'))
```

that I would like to add '0's to, to make so that they all have the same number of characters (3). How can I do this?

```
IDs2 <- c('000', '001', '002')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `stringr::str_pad`:

```
library(stringr)
IDs <- as.character(c('0', '01', '002')) 

str_pad(IDs, width = 3, pad = '0')
# [1] "000" "001" "002"
```

Or use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf('%03s', IDs)
# [1] "000" "001" "002"
```